# How to Add Category Filter in WordPress Post Query

Tags: php, wordpress

I filtered the post's in my sidebar by using this code,

```
$mostlikequerystr = "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.* 
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'most_liked' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' 
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value DESC
    LIMIT 0 , 10";
```

This code working perfect , but now i want to add a category filter too..

for this i used $term_id

```
global $wpdb;
$term_id = get_term_by('slug','trailers');
$term_id->term_id;
echo $term_id;//Prints 12 
$mostlikequerystr="SELECT $wpdb->posts.*  FROM $wpdb->posts,$wpdb->postmeta
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.$wpdb->taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $term_id 
AND $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'most_liked'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'categories'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish')
        LIMIT 0 , 10";

        $tariler_post = $wpdb->get_results($mostlikequerystr, 'OBJECT');
         echo $wpdb->show_errors();
```

but its not working for me and no error too ...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing with conditional operator in your `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $term_id here
                                               ^^^^^
    $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
```

Try this one by adding `AND`

```
$mostlikequerystr = "
SELECT $wpdb->posts.*  FROM $wpdb->posts,$wpdb->postmeta
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.$wpdb->taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $term_id 
AND $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id 
AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = 'most_liked'
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'categories'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
ORDER BY $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value DESC
)
        LIMIT 0 , 10";
```

If you are using `WPDB` class try to catch the errors

```
<?php $wpdb->show_errors(); ?>
```

Other way you can use WP's built in functions

```
$args = array(
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'meta_query' => array(
 array(
        'key' => 'most_liked',
        'value' => '',
        'compare' => '!='
    ),
'category__in' => 'id here or skip this argument'
'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
);
$tariler_post=new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: I fixed it but still have the same issue blank output, also no error

Comment: You need to post the complete code above query code doesn't provide the information for the blank page error it might be on some where in your code

Comment: Have you initialized `$wpdb` as `global` before calling `$wpdb->get_results(..)` like `global $wpdb;`